# Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Environment:

```
 "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.0.1"
```

qrcodescaner Users$ react-native run-android Scanning

> folders for symlinks in
>   /Users/Desktop/reactnativeapps/qrcodescaner/node_modules
>   (9ms) JS server already running. Building and installing the app on
>   the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/Desktop/reactnativeapps/qrcodescaner/android/build.gradle'
>     line: 6
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'qrcodescaner'.
>     Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Comment: try adding `google()` in *android/build.gradle* in `buildscript->repositories` section. https://imgur.com/a/2cK7P1V

Comment: @Cherniv Adding `google()` did nothing to resolve the issue.

Comment: could you please paste your gradle file here /android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

downgrade **react-native-camera** version to **1.0.0** and check again

Go to ProjectRoot\Android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties,

and change the distributionUrl value to:

"https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the `react-native-sqlite-storage` module. It turned out that the latest version (3.3.9) had been updated to work with the next version of gradle. That update included a [reference](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/blob/3.3.9/src/android-native/build.gradle) to `google()`.

I uninstalled it and did `npm install --save --save-exact react-native-sqlite-storage@3.3.8` and it worked, `google()` reference [gone](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/blob/3.3.8/src/android-native/build.gradle).

As far as i could see there was no mention of the breaking change in the [release notes](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/releases) for the 3.3.9 version. It could be this doesn't happen to most people.

Upshot: Why did they change the required gradle version? The latest React Native (v0.57) updated to the next gradle version too. I may be wrong, but it looks like you can't use a module if it requires a different gradle version from the one your project uses, urgh.